# Coq calculational style biconditional chain

Tags: coq, proof

I am trying to prove a biconditional in Coq:

```
P <-> Q
```

And I wrote down a proof that has this structure:

```
P 
<-> 
S 
<->
T
<->
Q
thus: P <-> Q
```

How can I mimic this calculational proof structure in Coq?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can express this in Coq. `intuition` is a tactic that is good at solving logical goals like yours.

```
Lemma lma P S T Q : (P <-> S) -> (S <-> T) -> (T <-> Q) -> (P <-> Q).
  intuition.
Qed.
```

If you prefer writing it explicitly, do:

```
Lemma lma P S T Q : (P <-> S) -> (S <-> T) -> (T <-> Q) -> (P <-> Q).
  intros [ps sp] [st ts] [tq qt].
  constructor.
  - intro p.
    apply tq.
    apply st.
    apply ps.
    apply p.
  - intro q.
    apply sp.
    apply ts.
    apply qt.
    apply q.
Qed.
```

Comment: how do I use lma then? How can I specify the values of P S T Q?

Comment: I think I would rather use the `transitivity` tactic.